# How to use browser caching with Amazon S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I get the following on gtmetrix.com:

```
Leverage browser caching    
E (55)
52%
Server  High
What does this mean?
The following cacheable resources have a short freshness lifetime. Specify an expiration at least one week in the future for the following resources:

http://mysite.s3.amazonaws.com/profile.png (expiration not specified)
http://mysite.s3.amazonaws.com/circle.player.css (expiration not specified)
http://mysite.s3.amazonaws.com/main.js (expiration not specified)
http://mysite.s3.amazonaws.com/not.the.skin.css (expiration not specified)
http://cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/slim-321711.css (expiration not specified)
```

I'm guessing the mailchimp files can't be modified.  But how do I specify a browser cache for Amazon S3 Cloudfront files?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you store files to s3. You can set custom headers which will be send to the client. In this case, you can set an Expires header for your files.

Cloudfront works a little bit differently as it depends on your origin.

Comment: There are two consoles: S3 Management Console, which is the useful one and Cloudfront console.  Can you say how the header is set in one of these?  I don't see any place for header info.

Comment: For s3 files you would go to properties -> metadata section for each file you want to update. Cloudfront takes headers from the origin.

Comment: Thanks.  Are there any examples of what key/value should be used to control browsing caching?

Comment: There are a couple you could look at. `Expires` takes a date, usually a far future one. However, if you make changes, you will likely need to version the filename. Otherwise returning users may keep the old version. Other headers to look at are `Cache-Control` and `Last-Modified`

Comment: Manually? One by one? What if you have thousands of files? What if you want to update these values?

Answer (score 29):

#### Via Amazon Management Console, select your file (or folder).

[image]

---

#### Go to the Properties tab and click on Metadata.

[image]

---

#### Finally, add Cache-Control to its header and save.

[image]

Comment: Manually? One by one? What if you have thousands of files? What if you want to update these values?

Comment: Then you should definitely use the AWS CLI: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/

Comment: you can add this to an entire folder in a bucket and it'll update all the contained objects

Comment: don't forget to also add the `Expires` header

Comment: Expires header is ignored if max-age is set.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Expires

Answer (score 12):

You can specify header parameter with the [s3cmd](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd)! while uploading files to s3.

eg :

```
s3cmd sync LOCAL_DIRECTORY s3://BUCKET[/PREFIX] --add-header=Cache-Control:max-age=3153600
```

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that this is also possible using [AWS CLI Tool's](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) [S3 Command](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/): `aws s3 sync $LOCAL s3://$REMOTE --cache-control "max-age=3153600"`