# Ember auto updating, user avatar hosted on S3 sends get request when new data comes in

Tags: amazon-s3, ember.js

I have a small communications app in Ember and the server is polled every 10 seconds for new data.

Next to each thread, or reply under a thread, there is a user area that displays the user's email, avatar, and badges. The avatars are hosted on s3, and every time the site sends down JSON data, a get request is sent off for each avatar on s3.

There are other images along side the avatars, like badge icons, but those are hosted in the Rails public folder and do not trigger a get request.

Why is this happening? is there a way to cache or suppress the get requests every time JSON is returned from the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is this happening?

1. Sounds like some of your views are re-rendering when it gets new data. It may be possible to prevent this by changing how your templates are structured, but probably that is overkill for this situation. If you want to see what's going on, try adding instrumentation to your app to console.log when views get re-rendered: [How to profile the page render performance of ember?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15673161/how-to-profile-the-page-render-performance-of-ember)
2. Assuming the avatars and other images are both getting re-rendered, the s3 ones probably trigger a new get request because the headers being returned by s3 are not set to allow browser caching.

> is there a way to cache or suppress the get requests every time JSON is returned from the server?

Yes, adjust settings on your s3 images so that browser will cache them.

- In s3 management console, go to properties -> metadata section for each file you want to update
- set an `Expires` header for your files
- other headers to look at are `Cache-Control` and `Last-Modified`
- See [How to use browser caching with Amazon S3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15502416/how-to-use-browser-caching-with-amazon-s3)

Comment: Thank you Mike, I have to adjust my s3 settings as the headers being returned are not set to allow browser caching. I am using Fog with public set to false, so an `AWSAccessKeyId` is generated and set to expire in 10 minutes... this could be challenging. If I use avatars from say gravatar, the issue goes away. Thank you for response.